# Synonymize [shortest-time] with [fastest-code]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [shortest-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-time) tag seems to mean the same as [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code).

It only has three questions tagged with it, so a manually retagging would be easy, but just so that someone searching for "time" can still find the tag: can the [shortest-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-time) tag be synonymized with [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)?

Comment: I in fact [suggested this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) over a year ago. <s>Although, no one seems to have reviewed the suggestion.</s> It seems that one person has.

Comment: This should be [tag:status-completed]